# (copy-sequence (cons 'foo 'bar)) => wrong-type-argument listp

Tags: list

In this example, there is a cons-cell `(foo . bar)` which needs a two (2) step approach so that it can be copied using `copy-sequence`:

- First, there needs to be a test to identify this particular type of cons-cell `(foo . bar)` so that the transformation function(s) are not unnecessarily applied to lists that are of a different form.
- Second, once this particular type of cons-cell is identified, the cons-cell needs to be transformed into a list that `copy-sequence` will accept.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Using your test in the first comment, and then creating the new list in your second comment, resolves the issue -- thank you very much!  I will also play with `proper-list-p`, which I haven't tried before.  Greatly appreciated.  I'm operating a `sort` function, which is *destructive* and I'd like to keep a copy of the original list for later use.

Comment: Comments now converted to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your test right there in the error message:

```
(copy-sequence (cons 'foo 'bar))
=> Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp bar)
```

I.e. for a cons cell CONS the test is:

```
(listp (cdr CONS))
```

You can also use `(proper-list-p CONS)` as a test, if you want to detect improper lists in general; but your example is more specific than this.

When your test fails, you could create a list from its components with:

```
(list (car CONS) (cdr CONS))
```

There's no point to calling `copy-sequence` on that, though -- you've *already* generated a new structure containing the values.